# Cannot read bucketed table with spark 2.4.8

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive

I have a Cloudera cluster version CDP 7.2 with Spark 2.4.8 (this is necessary as it's a migration and before moving to Spark 3 we want to ensure everything is working well), Hive 3.1, among other services. As a file system, I am using an S3 bucket, which is configured in Hive and set up so that the metastore points to it correctly.
When I write any table with saveAsTable, the result is correct and I can read it afterward.
When I add partitionBy='columnName' to saveAsTable, everything also goes well.
The problem arises when I add bucketBy(numberOfBuckets, 'columnName'), which first gives me this warning:

```
WARN hive.HiveExternalCatalog: Persisting bucketed data source table database.table into Hive metastore in Spark SQL specific format, which is NOT compatible with Hive
```

And then, when trying to read it, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 381, in show
print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in call
File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
return f(*a, **kw)
File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o80.showString.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid bucket file s3a://bucket_name/xxx/database.db/tabla/part-00000-d70703f3-dbfa-493f-a9e8-ee94966202ac_00000-12d01af1-6c85-49c3-b986-f88ed963938c.c000.snappy.parquet
```

I have tried different options that I found, like these:

```
hive.enforce.bucketing=false
hive.enforce.sorting=false

spark.sql('create table...')
spark.sql('MSCK REPAIR TABLE table_name')
```

Without any results.

UPDATE:

I have found the error:

Spark is writing the sequence number inside the name instead of at the end. By modifying the name of the file and adding _sequential at the end I am able to read the data correctly.

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?